# Why is String.Trim not trimming a semicolon?

Tags: c#, string, trim

I'm trying to trim a string with String.Trim:

```
split[2].Trim(';')
```

But I'm getting the result of:

```
System;
```

Instead of:

```
System
```

I also tried using:

```
split[2].TrimEnd(';')
```

But it still returns the same result.

Also if I do:

```
split[2].Trim('S', ';')
```

I get:

```
ystem;
```

I'm really confused why this is happening. Could it be because the semicolon is not the last character in the string?

Here is the full code:

```
string line = @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
class HelloWorld
{
    static void Main()
    {
#if DebugConfig
        Console.WriteLine("WE ARE IN THE DEBUG CONFIGURATION");  
#endif

        Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show("Itsyeboi", "Yup", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}"
string[] split = line.Split(' ', '\n');
while (true)
{
    if (split[counter4] == "using")
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = split[1].Trim(';');
        break;
    }
    else
    {
          richTextBox1.Text = line;
        break;
    }
}
```

It's true that my while loop is pointless, but it is "WIP" and not the final version.

Comment: Please check the length of the returned string. Maybe the `;` is not the trailing character.

Comment: what is even going on in that while loop? you always break after one round so why do you even need it?

Comment: @Staeff It's not finished yet, I'm going to remove the break in the first if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
string[] split = line.Split(' ', '\n');
```

With this:

```
string[] split = line.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Split(' ', '\n');
```

This will replace any carriage returns with just newline characters, removing the possibility that a trailing `\r` may be causing your problem.

Comment: With regard of .net core it probably is preferable to use Enviornment.NewLine() instead of "\r\n" (btw since its two characters you won't be able to use it as a single char)

Comment: Just in case anyone gets confused, `Environment.NewLine()` works regardless of whether you're using .NET Core. But as @Staeff pointed out, in the context of .NET Core being cross-platform, it's important not to assume that `\r\n` is always how lines are ended.

Answer (score 0):

If this answer is wrong, I'll delete it. As the information is sparse, this is only a wild guess.

Inserting a

```
split[2].Trim()
```

right befor the

```
split[2].Trim(';')
```

will most likely do the trick.

If not, but you know the last char is a `;` and you only want to get rid of this you may also just slice your array. This would probably be more efficient, as you would not need to compare any chars, while this is most likely done at least twice if you use `TrimEnd` or thrice if you yous `Trim`